# View.OnFocusChangeListener for views other than EditView

Tags: android

I have a list view which is displayed when another view on the layout is pressed . and i want it to disappear if i click outside of list . but somehow its not entering the `onFocusChange()` method.

Is it possible to use `View.OnFocusChangeListener` for views other than `EditView` ?